# Multi threading for my MFC C++ .dll

Tags: python, multithreading, dll, mfc

Currently I am accessing my MFC C++ dll using my python script and everything works well so far. My next step is to continuously access my .dll and carry on various operations with it simultaneously from which I feel "**Multi-threading**" is a very good option. Could you guys suggest me any good links to learn on multi-threading and implement in my application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/python_MFC_UI.aspx) tutorial would of great help to you considering what you are planning to do. Additionally, you can look into [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) for carrying out the operations the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

On which side of things are you interested in multi-threading, Python or MFC? If Python, consider multi-process, because of the Python GIL issue.

http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf

http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

If windows, I can help you a little bit from memory. If you tell more, we can help you better.

[Edit]
If this is an MFC question, you might want to add a tag.

Comment: Actually regardless of which side is doing the threading, the OP will need to learn about MFC threading (for thread safety, if nothing else).

Comment: I would want to go ahead with multi-threading in MFC. MFC tag was always there from the beginning.